# Emacs: abbrev-mode not expanding simple abbrev, possible causes?

Tags: emacs

I would like to assign the string 'target="_blank"' to the abbreviation 'tgt' as I use this a lot and it's annoying to have to type out each time.

The string above probably needs escapes and so on, so as a simpler starting point I have tried to assign 'target' to 'tgt'. Despite switching on `abbrev-mode` and defining this as a global abbrev, if I type 'tgt' and hit space, nothing happens. If I do `M-x list-abbrevs` I get this:

```
(global-abbrev-table)

"target"       1    "tgt"
```

So it seems to be recorded. I would have expected tgt to be expanded to target when I hit a space after tgt, but that doesn't happen. What am I missing? Have I completely misunderstood the nature of abbrevs? I have looked at the [Emacs wiki page](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/AbbrevMode) but like many Emacs pages it gives a number of complex solutions and annoyingly sparse coverage of the basics.

EDIT: embarassingly enough this looks like it was a combination of the wrong abbrev file and an assignment that was reversed, so that typing 'target' produced 'tgt'. I now have 'tgt' producing 'target="_blank"' as desired. Apologies everybody.

However, I now have a related question. This abbreviation expands when I hit space and typically I do not want a space after the 'target="_blank"' string. Is there a way to automatically remove the space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define the abbrev the other way around. The way you did it will expand "target" into "tgt".

To do the right thing, first type into a buffer *what you want the abbrev to expand into*. In your case that would be "target". Then, with the point right after the word, type <kbd>C-x a g</kbd>. This will prompt you for an abbrev for which you would type "tgt".

Et voilà: if `abbrev-mode` is turned on, typing <kbd>tgt</kbd>  will now expand into "target".

There are other ways to define an abbrev, e.g. via `M-x define-global-abbrev`, thus it's best to check out the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Defining-Abbrevs.html).

The problem with removing the space after the abbrev is that Emacs will insert it *after* the abbrev has been expanded. So hitting space will basically two things: trigger the expansion of the abbrev and then run the normal self-insert command.

One simple way to avoid this is to type <kbd>C-x '</kbd> or <kbd>C-x a e</kbd> to explicitly expand an abbrev rather then turning on `abbrev-mode`. Except, that's a bit annoying. If we look at the documentation again, however, we find:

> Function: **define-abbrev** *table name expansion &optional hook count*
>
> [...]
>
> If *hook* is a non-nil symbol whose no-self-insert property is
>   non-nil, hook can explicitly control whether to insert the
>   self-inserting input character that triggered the expansion. If hook
>   returns non-nil in this case, that inhibits insertion of the
>   character. By contrast, if hook returns nil, expand-abbrev also
>   returns nil, as if expansion had not really occurred.

This means that if you put the following lines in, say, your ".emacs" file:

```
(defun my-after-abbrev-expand ()
  (when (looking-back "\"\"\\|''\\|()\\|\\[\\]\\|{}")
    (backward-char 1))
  t)
(put 'my-after-abbrev-expand 'no-self-insert t)
```

then you can define an abbrev like so:

```
(define-abbrev global-abbrev-table "tgt" "target=\"\"" 'my-after-abbrev-expand)
```

to avoid the insertion of the space character. Also, the `my-after-abbrev-expand` function will move the point one position to the left if the expansion ends in two double quotes, two single quotes, or a pair of round, square or curly braces.

Comment: thank you, that was exactly what was happening. Would you have any thoughts on my edited question above, namely how to automatically delete the space after an expanded abbreviation?

Comment: @SlowLearner Yes, I just added how to avoid the insertion of the space character.

Comment: @SlowLearner Of course you can make up a different symbol that is shorter to type instead of `inhibit-space-after-abbrev-expansion`.

Comment: tested and seems to work well - many thanks. Another long-standing frustration removed!

Comment: @SlowLearner Actually, I just updated the answer one more time to improve it just a bit more: I replaced `inhibit-space-after-abbrev-expansion` with a function `my-after-abbrev-expand` that checks if the exansion ends in `""` and if so moves `point` between the two quote characters. Hope that makes it even more useful for you.